# How to add multiple components on same page?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started an Angular app so I want to add multiple components on same page. How does this work in Angular? Let's assume each div will be a separate component as well as the view. The components must be in separate .ts files.

Would the following work?

app.component.html:

```
<div>APP Component1</div>
<div>App Component2</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent1 {
    title = 'app works!';
}

export class AppComponent2 {
    title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: Add one more @Component just above AppComponent2 class and import it in app.module.ts

Comment: you should probably look more into about how decorators work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to do that, you actually need 3 components. The main component of the Angular application, and the two components you want to display. That would give the following file structure.

---

### The main component

**app.component.html**:

```html
<div>{{title}}</div>
<app-comp1></app-comp1>
<app-comp2></app-comp2>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'App works!';
}
```

---

### Component n°1

**comp1.component.html**:

```html
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

**comp1.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-comp1',
    templateUrl: './comp1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent1 {
    title = 'AppComponent1 works!';
}
```

---

### Component n°2

**comp2.component.html**:

```html
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

**comp2.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-comp2',
    templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./comp2.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent2 {
    title = 'AppComponent2 works!';
}
```

Comment: Of course with a complete application, you would have a main `<app-root>` that contains a `<router-outlet>` which includes the right component depending on the context (page, access rights, url, etc.)

Comment: Do we need `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html with this approach ?

Comment: You need a `router-outlet` if you want to use Angular's Router method which is, in theory, optional but in practice indispensable for most cases since you often navigate on an UI. More info on routing with Angular: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: As I wrote it, the two components are displayed on the main component at once, one above the other. If you want a condition for displaying one **or** the other, you need navigation and a router.

Comment: thats what i was trying to understand i want mutliple components on main component no navigation and routing involved here. trying to implement your answer

Comment: Then my answer does not involve neither navigation nor routing, please accept the answer if it's what solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

**@Component** here, is called **decorator** and it applies to single class following it. So creating another class will not make any effect.

It is advised to create a new component with a new class. Variables and functions of that class will be in the scope of that component.

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';  //component 1
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';  //component 2

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet,HomeComponent,TestComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
    
    title = 'Helow World'; 
}
```

This is Angular v17 where we use standalone components where we dont need Ng.Module.ts you can directly import the component into to your root component. here 2 components are imported HomeComponent & TestComponet. which later can be declared in HTML with there selectors value to render the component.

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-test></app-test>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).