# Lose the rendering when adding components on same page

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add multiple components on same page. But when I added the component header. I had no more rendering on the localhost. But if I delete the header, I have the rendering again. However, for the first case as for the other I have no error on the terminal. I already checked [this answer by Adrien Brunelat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417216/4764604) but it seems everything was okay on my side.

## Main component

### app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-menu></app-menu>
```

### app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'conFusion';
}
```

## Header component

### header.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span><img src="/assets/images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></span>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="container jumbotron"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column" 
    fxLayout.xs="column" 
    fxLayoutAlign.xs="start center"
    fxLayoutAlign.sm="start center" 
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-sm="center center" 
    fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <div fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="50%">
    <h1>Ristorante Con Fusion</h1>
    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations
      will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="20%">
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div fxFlex></div>
</div>
```

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'Header works!';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Menu works perfectly I can share it with you as well if you needtit. My repository is private as well but I can share it with you.

Here is [the Stackblitz](https://github.com/antoinecomp/conFusion) (I did it !!). It returns this error I didn't had in my terminal :

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.2.3/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2603:21)
Can't resolve all parameters for MenuComponent: (?).
```

## Versions

I have angular8.2.2

Comment: Please provide an minimum reproduction example using stackblitz or similar.

Comment: Yes definitely no reason you shouldn't be able to do this, but will be much clearer the problem if there is a quick stackblitz to look at

Comment: In header.compent.html start commenting stuff until it works. Old trick! ;) If everything is commented in it. It must be something with the declaration or something. But I suspect maybe something with css

Comment: Provide the code of the Menu at least, so we can try both at the same time. I made a stackblitz with the code provided and the header is working perfectly:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c496j2

Comment: @kvetis Thank you all for your tips, I didn't knew this tool. And wasn't able to import my bitbucket repository, or to click and drag from my computer. Nevertheless you can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/AntoineCompagnie/confusion2/src/master/)

Comment: @ThePassenger: The reason I'm asking is that it is not clear from the code you have provided what the problem might be. Creating it on stackblitz is not about copying all your code, but just the parts in which the problem is happening. Sometimes, when you do that, a solution is found much quicker. Nobody will do your work for you and go through your whole repository. We help you solve your problems in our free time. Please respect that.

Comment: @kvetis, yes I did one which I provided in the updated question. I respect that you solve my problems in your free time.

Comment: @Exomus Yes, it worked perfectly as well. Yet when I added few other components in the stackblitz I provided in the updated question I had `Can't resolve all parameters for MenuComponent: (?).`

Comment: The stackblitz link aims to GitHub I was talking about linking an stacblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywcwix . And the minimal reproduction is about adding only as little code that can demonstrate your problem :-)

Comment: I made a StackBlitz from your repository git:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c496j2

Cannot find any problems on display

Comment: @Exomus Yes ! I can see the differences. It is strange because the only thing I did was following [the instructions of exercise of the course I'm following](https://www.coursera.org/learn/angular/supplement/Cz6ZK/exercise-instructions-header-and-footer). Do you advise me to copy the parts of your code and remove from my project the files that are not in yours that works very well?

Comment: I would not advise you to do so. We are here to find your problem and solve it, not going around it. I have some time today, I am gonna clone your repository to see the problem in your project. I come back to you

Comment: @Exomus I have something very weird: [the stackblitz of the github repository](https://stackblitz.com/github/antoinecomp/conFusion) is now rendering everything very well (I didn't add or modified anything) but that's not the case locally, even if everything compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to declare the module I was using in `app.module.ts` :

```
...
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    DishdetailComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
...
```

I don't know the reason why it wasn't showing any error.